# Where does all the electric energy get dissipated in any electrical system?

Tags: power, heat, thermal, energy, efficiency

I know that some portion of the electrical energy is dissipated as heat due to the efficiency, but where does the other energy go?

If we are talking about a satellite in space, all of the electrical energy is dissipated in terms of heat. How does the work done energy dissipate, also in terms of heat?

Comment: One word: radiation.

Comment: Not just radiation:- https://www.nasa.gov/centers/glenn/about/fs21grc.html "Ion thrusters (based on a NASA design) are now being used to keep over 100 geosynchronous Earth orbit communication satellites in their desired locations"

Answer (score 7):

Satellite in space will also radiate energy by radio waves, intentional and unintentional and thermal radiation. It will also absorb radiation and make use of it powering in it's own instrumentation (solar panels). Some energy is transferred to gravitational potential energy or kinetic energy.

If the satellite is unable to emit enough energy through thermal radiation it will heat until the emitted radiation equals generated + absorbed radiation.

Answer (score 6):

The initial rocket energy used to put a satellite into orbit is converted into the kinetic energy of the moving mass. In a vacuum, that energy continues to be stored as potential energy. Additional energy is not needed or used to keep the satellite in orbit. To the extent that space is not quite a total vacuum, some energy is lost as heat due to friction, and the satellite will eventually fall to earth if it does not have rocket energy to sustain orbit.

In general, electrical energy is converted to other forms of energy like heat, electromagnetic waves including light and radio transmissions, and mechanical energy including motion of mass and sound. In some equipment, electrical energy is converted to electrical energy with different parameters, different frequency, voltage or current. All conversions involve losses that are ultimately dissipated as heat. All electromagnetic radiation is ultimately absorbed by mass and converted to heat.

Electrical energy that is used for information technology is used to change the state of temporary or "permanent" memory devices. That energy is ultimately dissipated as heat or transmitted to another system.

Mechanical energy is used to add kinetic energy to mass by initiating or increasing kinetic energy or moving mass to a position of higher gravitational energy. It is also used to overcome friction or change the shape of solid materials. All of those process involve friction including aerodynamic and hydraulic drag. All friction energy is converted to heat.

All energy is ultimately dissipated as heat except to the extent that is stored. Most storage of energy is not absolutely stable and free from losses.

Comment: +1 for "All energy is ultimately dissipated as heat". Indeed, the second law of thermodynamics requires this.

Answer (score 2):

> But where does the other energy go?

Conservation of energy principle says that the energy cannot go anywhere. Energy can be converted into a different form of energy, can be converted, and can be transferred.

So the electrical energy can be converted into different forms of energy, such as motion, audio, light, etc.

- Motors convert electrical energy to motion or torque.
- Speakers are a different form of motors, and they convert electrical energy to motion, but we get that motion as audio/sound.
- Bulbs/LEDs convert electrical energy to light (electromagnetic waves, in general)

For a satellite in space, some of the energy is converted into motion so that it can move around the globe, and some of the electrical energy is converted into electromagnetic waves for satellite communication.

Not all of the energy is converted into heat.

Comment: I disagree with your statement that "energy cannot go anywhere".  We move energy around all the time.  More correctly the energy in an isolated system stays the same.  So it depends on where you draw your boundaries.

Comment: @jwh20 it was a response to the question statement "where does the energy go?". What I meant was that if there's energy, it can't go anywhere by itself. It should be transferred (with or without conversion) by an external "force" *(Don't take this as its lateral meaning)*. For example, heat cannot move by itself, there should be a temperature difference. The energy stored in an ideal battery does not decrease over time.